# How to use update_post_meta when inserting an new post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, metadata, input-field

How do I use `update_post_meta()` to put the value from this:

```html
<input type="text" name="gname" id="gname">
```

on here:

```html
<input type="text" name="budget" value="" style="width:100%;" fdprocessedid="ectck">
```

I'm a beginner in PHP and my task is to put the input value from `gname` to a custom field, using `update_post_meta()`, which has `name="budget"`.

Here is my working code, but it cannot put the value on `budget`:

```php
<?php
////////// INSERT WP POST
if (isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['gname']) && isset($_POST['hname'])) {

    $my_post = array(
        'post_type' =>  'job',
        'post_title' => $_POST['fname'],
        'post_content' => $_POST['hname'],
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    // Get the value of the source input field
    $gname_value = $_POST['gname'];
    
    // Get the post ID
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    
    // Update the target input field with the value
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'budget', $gname_value);

    wp_insert_post($my_post);
}
?>
```

I'm using WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

When using `wp_insert_post()` you can use [**'meta_input'** argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#parameters) to add metadata on the fly, instead of using afterward `update_post_meta()`.

Note that the function `wp_insert_post()` will return the post ID.

So your code will be:

```php
<?php
///// INSERT WP POST /////
if ( isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['gname']) && isset($_POST['hname']) ) {
 
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_type'    =>  'job',
        'post_title'   => sanitize_text_field($_POST['fname']),
        'post_content' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['hname']),
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'meta_input'   => array(
            'budget'   => sanitize_text_field($_POST['gname']),
        ),
    ) );
}
// Get budget value
$budget = get_post_meta($post_id, 'budget', true);

// Populate budget value in your input field
?>
<input type="text" name="budget" value="<?php echo $budget; ?>" style="width:100%;" fdprocessedid="ectck">
<?php
```

Or using `update_post_meta()` it will be like:

```php
<?php
///// INSERT WP POST /////
if ( isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['gname']) && isset($_POST['hname']) ) {
 
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_type'    =>  'job',
        'post_title'   => sanitize_text_field($_POST['fname']),
        'post_content' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['hname']),
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
    ) );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'budget', sanitize_text_field($_POST['gname']));
    }
}
// Get budget value
$budget = get_post_meta($post_id, 'budget', true);

// Populate budget value in your input field
?>
<input type="text" name="budget" value="<?php echo $budget; ?>" style="width:100%;" fdprocessedid="ectck">
<?php
```

Comment: lastly how do i add or change the "hname" to be like "gname" , the "hname" should be a update_post_meta to "skill-needed".